# Why don't the jquery datatable never reinitialize?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have trying to get it right but failed. The problem is that when I call filltblServicesReport function which initializes database mainly, it works for the first time but when I call it again then it doesn't load the new data. Eventhough I am destroying it but still it doesn't.

I am loading it via click event of a button.

```
function filltblServicesReport() {

            $('tfoot td#tdTotal').text("");

            var url = '@Url.Action("DetailedServiceReport")';
            var data = { FromDate: $("#FromDate").val(), ToDate: $("#ToDate").val() }

            $.post(url, data, function (response) {

                if (response.ReturnStatusJSON == true) {

                    $("#tbodytblServicesReport").html("");

                    var i = 1;

                    $.each(response.lstDetailedServicesReturned, function (i, val) {

                        $("#tblServicesReport").append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').html(i))
                         .append($('<td>').html((val.EntryDateTime === null || val.EntryDateTime === "") ? "N/A" : formatJSONDate(val.EntryDateTime)))
                         .append($('<td>').html(val.InvoiceNo))
                         .append($('<td>').html(val.CustomerName))
                         .append($('<td>').html(val.VehicleRegNo))
                         .append($('<td>').html(val.ServiceName))
                         .append($('<td>').html(val.ServicePrice))
                         .append($('<td>').html(val.Commission))
                        )

                        i++;

                        $('tfoot td#tdTotal').text(val.TotalCost);
                        $('tfoot td#tdTotalCommission').text(val.TotalCommission);
                    })


                    $('#tblServicesReport').show();

                   // $('#tblServicesReport').dataTable().fnDestroy();

                    $('#tblServicesReport').DataTable({

                        destroy: true,
                        bPaginate: false,
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
               'copyHtml5',
               'excelHtml5',
               'csvHtml5',
               {
                   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                   footer: true,
                   title: 'Services Report (' + $('#FromDate').val() + ' - ' + $('#ToDate').val() + ')',
                   customize: function (doc) {
                       doc.styles.title = {
                           color: 'gray',
                           fontSize: '15',
                           alignment: 'center'
                       }

                       doc.content[1].table.widths =
                           Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');

                       doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 10;
                       doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'left';
                       doc.styles.tableHeader.color = 'white'



                   }
               },
               {
                   extend: 'print',
                   footer: true
                   //title: 'Sales Report'
               }

                        ]
                    });


                }
                else {

                    swal("Sorry !", "No Record Found", "error");
                    $("#tbodytblServicesReport").html("");

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You can initialize the table at the start and then feed the data into the table when the button is clicked using data and columns which are already integrated into the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tblServicesReport').DataTable.ajax.url.load
```

Solved it. You can use .ajax.url.load with data table to reinitialize it.